# 301 redirect from multiple url parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect any of these formats

```
mydomain.com/?main_page=products_new
mydomain.com/?main_page=products_new&page=2
mydomain.com/?main_page=products_new&disp_order=2
```

to this

```
mydomain.com/new-products
```

I have this working for only the first parameter. How can I ignore the remaining ones and match on anything that contains **?main_page-products_new** ?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^main_page=products_new [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /new-products? [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache supports [RedirectMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)

`RedirectMatch 301 ^main_page=products_new.*$ /new-products?$1`

Comment: That isn't working. I use RedirectMatch for other urls without a problem.

Comment: What if you change ^main... into ^.main ?